# Can't disable popUp dialogbox and keyboard at on touch outside

Tags: react-native, npm

I am using react-native-popup-dialog npm for popups.Problem is when I click outside of popup it only closes popup but keyboard is still live.I need to double tap outside to dismiss popup and keyboard at the same time.Any body facing this issue?Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should disable the keyboard manually by using `Keyboard.dismiss()`, Keyboard is to be imported from `react-native`.

So your code should look like:

```
<Dialog
    visible={this.state.visible}
    onTouchOutside={() => {
      this.setState({ visible: false }, () => Keyboard.dismiss());
    }}
  >
....
```

Comment: I use popUp.show() & popUp.dismiss()... there is no property onTouchOutside available

Comment: Have seen the library you stated [react-native-popup-dialog](https://github.com/jacklam718/react-native-popup-dialog), I can see there a prop called `onTouchOutside` thats a callback which gets invoked on touching the outside section. 

If thats not the correct library then too you can always use `Keyboard.dismiss()` after your `popUp.dismiss()`

Answer (score 0):

u can use the properties of the dialogue package which u have to use. Set `onTouchOutside` and manage ur state flag `visible` true or false.

Example :
import Dialog, { DialogContent } from 'react-native-popup-dialog';
import { Button } from 'react-native'

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Button
    title="Show Dialog"
    onPress={() => {
      this.setState({ visible: true });
    }}
  />
  <Dialog
    visible={this.state.visible}
    onTouchOutside={() => {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }}
  >
    <DialogContent>
      {...}
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
</View>
```

Link [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog)